# Калькулируемое поле

Tags: javascript

В общем-то идея проста. Есть инпут под первое число, есть инпут под второе число. Третий инпут должен быть суммой двух предыдущих.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом JS - http://jsfiddle.net/1tgz0vqv/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QW01_01/1tgz0vqv/